# How can I download a file and display progress in Android?

Tags: android, concurrency, download

1. I am trying to download a file in android and display the progress
   of downloading in progressbar

   1. show the downloading speed in textview
   2. show the size of the file in textview

   **while downlaoding the file**

I have been able to display the progress bar concurrently, but in a for loop,
At the moment when I run the code is giving me error: **NullPointerExceptoin**. but doesn't say on which line it also gives me **FileNotFoundException**. and I don't know what I am doing wrong. **I am pretty new to Android** so if anyone can help it would be great. Here is the code. I have provided the permisions in the manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

and here is the activity, I use only this activity.

```
public class DownloadActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    TextView view1;
    TextView view2;
    TextView view3;
    ProgressBar bar;
    Button startButton;
    String contents;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_download);
        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        startButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
//        contents = urlToString("https://www.dropbox.com/home/Music/FOX%20-%20Pokazn%D0%BE%CC%81%20(2012)");
        contents = "http://sdlc-esd.sun.com/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/7u9-b05/jre-7u9-windows-i586.exe?AuthParam=1355055216_89a14482cb59e95946db732dc4341468&GroupName=JSC&FilePath=/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/7u9-b05/jre-7u9-windows-i586.exe&File=jre-7u9-windows-i586.exe&BHost=javadl.sun.com";
        urlToString(contents);
//        http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/10MB.zip
//        http://sdlc-esd.sun.com/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/7u9-b05/jre-7u9-windows-i586.exe?AuthParam=1355055216_89a14482cb59e95946db732dc4341468&GroupName=JSC&FilePath=/ESD6/JSCDL/jdk/7u9-b05/jre-7u9-windows-i586.exe&File=jre-7u9-windows-i586.exe&BHost=javadl.sun.com
    }


    public void onClick(View view) {

        // detect the view that was "clicked"
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            new LongOperation().execute(1000 + "");
            break;
        }
    }

    private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                // this will be useful so that you can show a typical 0-100% progress bar
                int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

                // download the file
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(contents);

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;
                int count;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) 
                {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress.... triggers the onProgressUpdate!
                    publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));

                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                try {


                    Thread.sleep(500);
                     publishProgress(i+1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return "URL:" + contents;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            txt.setText(result);
        }

        @Override
          protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            bar.setProgress(values[0]);
            view1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            view2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            view3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);


            view1.setText("URL: " +  contents);
            view2.setText("File Size: "  + "x");
            view3.setText("Transfer Rate: "  + "y" );
          }
    }



//  Log.v("********", getLinkRate());

    private String urlToString(String address) {
        HttpURLConnection con = null;
        URL url;
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(address);
            con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setReadTimeout(10000);
            con.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.connect();
            is = con.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedReader reader = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);

                Log.d("*******", line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (is != null) {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

LogCat:

```
12-09 12:53:57.608: D/*******(824): Ty���mk�B$1�-2
12-09 12:53:57.648: D/dalvikvm(824): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 202K, 62% free 7797K/20487K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 31ms
12-09 12:53:57.648: I/dalvikvm-heap(824): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 7981588-byte allocation
12-09 12:53:57.669: D/dalvikvm(824): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1K, 62% free 7796K/20487K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 26ms
12-09 12:53:57.669: E/dalvikvm-heap(824): Out of memory on a 7981588-byte allocation.
12-09 12:53:57.669: I/dalvikvm(824): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
12-09 12:53:57.678: I/dalvikvm(824):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4001f1a8 self=0xce48
12-09 12:53:57.678: I/dalvikvm(824):   | sysTid=824 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1345006528
12-09 12:53:57.678: I/dalvikvm(824):   | schedstat=( 6672852716 8933397811 8674 )
12-09 12:53:57.678: I/dalvikvm(824):   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:~95)
12-09 12:53:57.678: I/dalvikvm(824):   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:153)
12-09 12:53:57.678: I/dalvikvm(824):   at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:217)
12-09 12:53:57.678: I/dalvikvm(824):   at tees.ac.uk.L1087591.DownloadActivity.urlToString(DownloadActivity.java:156)
12-09 12:53:57.678: I/dalvikvm(824):   at tees.ac.uk.L1087591.DownloadActivity.onClick(DownloadActivity.java:54)
12-09 12:53:57.678: I/dalvikvm(824):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
12-09 12:53:57.678: I/dalvikvm(824):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
12-09 12:53:57.678: I/dalvikvm(824):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-09 12:53:57.678: I/dalvikvm(824):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-09 12:53:57.678: I/dalvikvm(824):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-09 12:53:57.678: I/dalvikvm(824):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-09 12:53:57.678: I/dalvikvm(824):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-09 12:53:57.678: I/dalvikvm(824):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-09 12:53:57.678: I/dalvikvm(824):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-09 12:53:57.678: I/dalvikvm(824):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-09 12:53:57.678: I/dalvikvm(824):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-09 12:53:57.688: D/AndroidRuntime(824): Shutting down VM
12-09 12:53:57.688: W/dalvikvm(824): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
12-09 12:53:57.688: E/AndroidRuntime(824): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-09 12:53:57.688: E/AndroidRuntime(824): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
12-09 12:53:57.688: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:95)
12-09 12:53:57.688: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:153)
12-09 12:53:57.688: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:217)
12-09 12:53:57.688: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at tees.ac.uk.L1087591.DownloadActivity.urlToString(DownloadActivity.java:156)
12-09 12:53:57.688: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at tees.ac.uk.L1087591.DownloadActivity.onClick(DownloadActivity.java:54)
12-09 12:53:57.688: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
12-09 12:53:57.688: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
12-09 12:53:57.688: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-09 12:53:57.688: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-09 12:53:57.688: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-09 12:53:57.688: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-09 12:53:57.688: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-09 12:53:57.688: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-09 12:53:57.688: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-09 12:53:57.688: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-09 12:53:57.688: E/AndroidRuntime(824):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-09 12:53:59.688: I/Process(824): Sending signal. PID: 824 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the code you are running actually goes trough `try{}catch(){}` block and only then continue with the rest of the code because if file is not found you should stop AsyncTask and display error message

You are calling your AsyncTask like this

```
new LongOperation().execute(1000 + "");
```

So you are passing `1000 + ""` as url argument ? When you declare AsyncTAsk like this

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
```

you are suppose to pass String as argument, you get Integer as progress for onProgressUpdate() and finally get String for result of AsyncTask

Also you can't have network on main thread in your `onCreate()` where you are calling

```
urlToString(contents);
```

Comment: I replaced it with .execut(contents) where contents is the url i wont to download but it is giving me the same error.

Comment: Well did you try to call contents from browser ? Maybe there is nothing to download

Comment: I tried you link in browser and it is not working - Error 6 (net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND): The file or directory could not be found.

Comment: I edited my answer, you need to check if your try - catch block has finished with success and then continue to execute some other code

Answer (score 1):

you have to debug your activity to find out which line throws the NullPointerException.

Comment: In the LogCat it doesn't say in which line it is, it only says it is in this activity which is the only one in the project

Comment: use breakpoint on oncreate function and step into your codes and your app will crash and throws error on line that throws NullPointerException So you can focus on that specific line

Answer (score 1):

In your OnCreate Function you are using a method called urlToString which creates a HTTPURLConnection, if your running it above 4.0 then your code will crash since the HHTP connections should be processed in background thread not on main thread

Comment: Well, I use API level 10 which is 2.3.3

Comment: then u have to debug your code and check whether u have set all the id's in your xml as per your code because that will cause NullpointerException

Answer (score 1):

You are starting the AsyncTask with "new LongOperation().execute(1000 + "")",
so the string "1000" is passed to the doInBackground method, then you started a URLConnection with the string "1000", but "1000" is a invalid url.
Maybe this is the error.

Comment: And the urlToString function with a long time urlConnection task must be block the UI thread. You must do URLConnection in a background thread.